# Hamming Window - Understanding Formula

Tags: signal-processing

I'm trying to understand the Hamming window concept (Signal Processing) and the equation looks like the following:

[image]

Where:

N = number of Samples in each frame

Y[n] = Output Signal

X(n) = Input Signal

W(n) = Hamming window

First Question: I have "framed" (split the signal into blocks), so therefore, in X(n) do I pass in the values for each block, and, not the block itself?

Second question regarding the Hamming Window:

The equation is given:

[image]

From this I get:

w(n) = new vector

e.g.
w(0) = 0.54 - 0.46 cos()

This is where I get lost. Shameful I know. Right, I know this is really stupid of me to ask but could someone help me out understanding the rest of this equation? I.e. in english steps?

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First Question: I have "framed" (split the signal into blocks), so therefore, in X(n) do I pass in the values for each block, and, not the block itself?

You have divided your entire signal in blocks of length $N$ (perhaps overlaping), and what follows is to be done for each block. So, in what follows $X(n)$ represents your input signal with $n=0$ being the start of your particular block.

> Second question regarding the Hamming Window:

(please dont post images for formulas here, learn to type equations in latex)
It seems you confused $N$ (fixed, window size) with $n$. The formula is

$$ w(n) = 0.54 - 0.46 \cos\left(\frac{2 \pi \, n}{N-1} \right)$$

If you graph this (image on the left [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Window_function_%28hamming%29.png)), you see that it's a smooth window peaked in the center of your block (N/2). To get $y(n)$, you just multiply, value by value:

$$y(n) = x(n) \, w(n)$$

BTW, this kind of question is better suited to https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hey - Take N = (Number of samples in each frame) = 256 .. So therefore will the values for w(n) range from 0 - 255 because N - 1?

Comment: The values of $n$ range from 0 to 255, yes.

Comment: So this equation.. w(0) = 0.54 - 0.46 * cos(2*pi / 255) = 0.28203645802 .. Is this correct? If so, the value shouldn't ever change, should it? Because every block N = 256 N-1 = 255

Comment: You are forgettin the $n$ in the numerator

Comment: but <mi>n</mi> is just ranging from 0 to 256 (block size) etc, right?

Comment: yes. but then when n=0 w(0)=  0.54 - 0.46 * cos(2*pi *0/ 255)  = 0.54-0.46=0.08

Comment: thank you :) got it now, just have to code it!! My result (from the hamming window) should look like the one you gave, right? I can plot these results in matlab

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6582/discussion-between-phorce-and-leonbloy)

Comment: Do I have to compute an FFT on this? Because in this example (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aWindow_function_%28hamming%29.png) which you gave, looks nothing like the results I get.. This does an FFT on it..